Using descriptors to compare oxide-phase bulk phase (crystal)
I have the xyz coordinates for multiple oxidized Pt nanoparticles (~ 2.5 nm diameter) at different oxygen content.
I would like to find the closest oxide phase match (PtO, PtO2, Pt3O6...). I think a way to have strong arguments would be to perform a direct comparison using geometrical descriptors. However one system is a bulk periodic crystal and one is an isolated nanoparticle in a box.
Could someone point to a descriptor, if possible available in (https://singroup.github.io/dscribe/latest/) to perform this ? Thanks a lot

